# ListInterpolation causing .cdf security problems?

Tags: cdf-format

I've made a simple `.cdf` that makes a function from a list of data I've provided in table form (using `ListInterpolation`) and plots it on a graph (no importing, exporting or conversion of data from string) and I still get a grey block when I try to post it online, indicating that I'm violating some security rule.  It works with the `{fullscreen: 'true'}` workaround, but I don't know what I'm doing that necessitates this.  Advice?  Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link to the CDF file?

Comment: Sure.  Here it is: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/79378685/materials%20for%20online%20use.cdf
There are a few very long data tables in there -- I wanted to avoid importing them or using SaveDefinitions...

Comment: How do you know it's the `ListInterpolation` that triggers this?

Comment: You could try wrapping `Manipulate` in `DynamicModule`, i.e. do something like `DynamicModule[{AgN, Agwave, AgNfunction, ..., xstart, xend}, Manipulate[...]]`

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily characterize this as something you are doing wrong or are able to change. Some of these things seem to be hit and miss at the moment. For example I have previously found that a tick function will cause grey boxes (a pure tick function will not). Apparently many of these sorts of things have been fixed in future releases.

Comment: Sjoerd - I can't say for certain that it's the ListInterpolation that causes the security issue.  I only suspect ListInterpolation because that's the only function that I haven't previously used in a .cdf and avoided this problem.

Heike and Mike H. - Thanks for the comments -- much appreciated.  I'll try the DynamicModule suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: The security issue is caused by the presence of the symbol ``Developer`PackedArrayForm`` in the interpolating function objects.  The Player FE, unfortunately, does not understand that this is a perfectly safe symbol to evaluate and locks down security as a result.  I haven't yet come up with a good way to work around this, but I'm still thinking about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

John Fultz's comment:

> The security issue is caused by the presence of the symbol `` Developer`PackedArrayForm `` in the interpolating function objects. The `Player FE`, unfortunately, does not understand that this is a perfectly safe symbol to evaluate and locks down security as a result. I haven't yet come up with a good way to work around this, but I'm still thinking about it.